# php number format value 999999 but output show 10000000

Tags: php

I try to use php number_format to show number like this xxx,xxx,xx.xx .

When I echo value it auto increment from 9999999 to 10000000.

Anyone has idea how to show data result 9,999,999?

```
<?php echo number_format(99999999,2); ?>
```

Comment: The code supplied would not make the number increment unless it is due to a rounding issue (as in the number is a float with a value like `99.999` would round to `100.00`). You can see the code you posted run in 150+ versions of php, all with the same output here: https://3v4l.org/fmOM9

Comment: If you are having problems with rounding on a variable, you can find that out by doing a var_dump on your variable and working out the rounding visually and if the number has more than two decimal places

Comment: are this 64 bit or 32 bit, also linux or win?

Comment: My windows is 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

`String number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )`

So, with your example:

`<?php echo number_format(9999999, 2, '.', ','); ?>`

Outputs:

`9,999,999.00`

Or if you did not want the decimals:

`<?php echo number_format(9999999, 0, '.', ','); ?>`

Outputs:

`9,999,999`

From php.net:

`This function accepts either one, two, or four parameters (not three)`

Just a reminder.

Comment: Just curious, but where do you see 3 arguments? The example code shows 2 and OP appears to be trying to find out why when they enter `999999` it is showing `1000000`.

Comment: I don't see three arguments. I never claimed to see 3 arguments either. The OP asked how to make the code supplied provide `9,999,999` as well. I answered that question.

Comment: Better. It wasn't wrong or anything, it just appeared that you were trying to correct them on something they were doing wrong.

Comment: Yes,  i have tried many way to get 9,999,999 in float value but it still show  10,000,000

Comment: Using just this raw code will **not** produce the result you're listing. 

https://3v4l.org/ClC2L

Tested on 150+ versions of PHP, same output. Something is wrong in your code.  Wait -- in float value? 9999999 is *not* a float, it is an integer. Are you typecasting? As you can see here https://3v4l.org/Wpf4n if you are typecasting as a float, you're going to get unpredictable results with `number_format`!

Comment: Make sure you are typecasting *before* you hit `number_format` with that value. If the returned value needs to be a float, it's not really going to work. You can't set a float as `9,999,999.00`. You have to set the float to `9999999` and simply set any *output* using `number_format`. This is how you *should* be developing anyway - numbers being stored should be raw, unformatted numbers. That way if you ever change formatting, it's an incredibly simple change throughout all existing stored values.